# jquery search and replace

Tags: php, jquery, html, smarty

This is the function that I have

```
function set(sub) {
    var input = prompt("Insert your desired " + sub + " information, leave blank if you use an automated system to generate this information.");
    $('#' + sub).html(input).show();
    var textarea = $('textarea');
    textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(sub+"=",sub+"="+input));
}
```

Usually the sub is s1, or s2, or s3. Now the issue is that I want the replaced value to reset if the input is blank.

So lets say I input that I want to set s1 to equal a, so in the text area it will replace s1= with, s1=a, now if the input is empty I want the s1=a to revert back to s1=

Comment: What does the <textarea> contain? What is it's purpose?

Comment: The textarea contains HTML code. User's click on a link and are able to insert values for S1, S2, S3 to their liking, once that is complete the S1, S2, or S3 is updated in the textarea. Problem is that if they want to update anyone of those and they leave the input area empty it doesn't update in the textarea, the input that they first put will stay.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfjzb/) close?

Comment: I don't use a drop down selector, http://pastebin.com/ybZ4iAWn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It uses a regular expression (Regex) to do the replacements.

```
function set(sub) {
    var input = prompt("Insert your desired " + sub + " information, leave blank if you use an automated system to generate this information.");
    $('#' + sub).html(input).show();

    var pattern = new RegExp('(' + sub + '=[^&]*)', 'ig');    
    var $textarea = $('textarea');

    // Do Replacements
    var content = $textarea.html().replace(pattern, sub + '=' + input);
    $textarea.html(content);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the html with something like:

```
$(selector).html(function(i, orig) {
    return orig.replace("1234", "5678");
});
```

Comment: Having some difficulties adding that into what I already have, mind showing me how you would do it?